# How to move list items to the right?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working on a portfolio website, and the footer section is not the way I want it to look. I want to move the unordered list items to the right side. I have tried justify-content: right;, justify-content: end;, and right, however, it doesn't work.

```css
.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  margin-top: 38px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  height: 700px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.footer-text {
  padding: 200px 100px;
  font-family: "Khula", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #bbbbbb;
  line-height: 80px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.footer-contact {
  font-family: "Khula", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #222222;
  line-height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.footer-text-color {
  color: #222222;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<footer class="content-container footer">

  <div class="footer-text">Let's <br> <span class="footer-text-color">Connect</span></div>

  <ul>

    <li><a href=a.html class="footer-contact">Email</a></li>
    <li><a href=b.html class="footer-contact">LinkedIn</a></li>
    <li><a href=c.html class="footer-contact">GitHub</a></li>
  </ul>

</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your `<ul>` a class. I called it `center`. Then add the following styles as seen in the CSS. Also, remove the `margin-left: 60px;` on `footer-contact` I re spaced them with a flex-box on the parent.

```css
.footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    height: 700px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.footer-text {
  padding: 200px 100px;
  font-family: "Khula", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #bbbbbb;
  line-height: 80px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.footer-contact {
  font-family: "Khula", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #222222;
  line-height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.footer-text-color {
  color: #222222;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li {
  text-align: right;
}

.center {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<footer class="content-container footer">

  <div class="footer-text">Let's <br> <span class="footer-text-color">Connect</span></div>
  
  <ul class="center">

    <li><a href=a.html class="footer-contact">Email</a></li>
    <li><a href=b.html class="footer-contact">LinkedIn</a></li>
    <li><a href=c.html class="footer-contact">GitHub</a></li>
  </ul>

</footer>
```

Comment: I want the email, LinkedIn and GitHub more to the right. I've tried float right on ui, and it works, however its not on the same line with the title.

Comment: @user8 What you mean more right, it is moved left from original post. How much more?

Comment: @user8 remove margins on parent, and use `space-between` on flex. See changes.

Comment: @user8 please provide a markup image if I am still not understanding you right.

Comment: its all good, finally got it to work. Thanks for your assistance :).

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `margin-right: 60px;` with `margin-right: 0;` in `footer-contact` and also add below CSS.

```
ul li {
  text-align: right;
}
```

I also update your code snippet, it'll help you out. Thank You

```css
.footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  grid-area: footer;
  margin-top: 38px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  height: 700px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.footer-text {
  padding: 200px 100px;
  font-family: "Khula", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #bbbbbb;
  line-height: 80px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.footer-contact {
  font-family: "Khula", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #222222;
  line-height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.footer-text-color {
  color: #222222;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<footer class="content-container footer">

  <div class="footer-text">Let's <br> <span class="footer-text-color">Connect</span></div>

  <ul>

    <li><a href=a.html class="footer-contact">Email</a></li>
    <li><a href=b.html class="footer-contact">LinkedIn</a></li>
    <li><a href=c.html class="footer-contact">GitHub</a></li>
  </ul>

</footer>
```

Comment: I want to move the email, LinkedIn, and GitHub more to the right.

Comment: @user8 to achieve your goal we have to use flex CSS, i also update code snippet. I also suggest you to avoid float and use flex CSS. Thank You